# How find specific value in array mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, document

guys i have such document in mongodb 4.2:

```
"DifferenceValue" : "[{\"PropertyName\":\"Id\",\"PropertyLabel\":\"\",\"CurrentValue\":2725,\"NextValue\":null},{\"PropertyName\":\"ClientIpAddress\",\"PropertyLabel\":\"\",\"CurrentValue\":\"192.168.1.203\",\"NextValue\":null},{\"PropertyName\":\"SessionId\",\"PropertyLabel\":\"\",\"CurrentValue\":\"b4sd54s6d4sr4\",\"NextValue\":null})}]"
```

how i can find the CurrentValue keys that has 2725 value in mongodb. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: db.Audit.find({DifferenceValue : {CurrentValue : 7880174}}).pretty() @Huber

Comment: Can you also add, your expected output

Comment: Show nothing @PuneetSingh

Comment: You want to find curretValues and you want a MongoDB query? so in which JSON format you are expecting your output, a sample JSON output would be good to understand you question better

Comment: Please provide a **valid** JSON document, then it is more likely that you will get an answer.

Comment: Try `db.collection.find({
  "DifferenceValue.CurrentValue": 2725
})`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

mongo query:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({'CurrentValue':2725})
```

pymongo query:

1. Connect to Mongo
2. get pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor
3. Then try -

   `for i in collection.find({'CurrentValue':2725}):
       print(i)
       break`